# How can I address the header in an md-File using jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I am using Jekyll to generate my website. 
Currently I am building a navigation bar for the different subpages. Basically I have different md-files with multiple sections and each section starts with a headers such as for example:

```
##header 1
content
##header 2
content
...
```

I try to build a navbar, that directs you to the paragraph on my subpage that you are clicking on. (Such as the navigation in Wikipedia)
The way, that I am currently using is to make one navigation.html for each subpage in my _includes folder. However, I am aware, that this might cause trouble, when the number of subpages increases.

What I want to do is basically:

```
{% for "header" in "each .md-file" %}
    <a href="#">{{ "name of header" }} </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I know for example, that in my  _posts/post I could just do

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
```

However, I the md-Files I want to use are in my root-Directory and I do not know how to call them specifically.

To sum up: I have multiple .md-files in my directory and want to get each ##header as a link in a table of content.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe, not exactly what you want, but you can let Kramdown generate a table of contents for navigation. For details, see: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @marcanuy suggest, I would put your files in a `_pages` directory. 
Be sure to add `include: ['_pages']` to your build settings in `_config.yml`

Now you can go through the pages with `{% for page in site.pages %}`
This still leaves the challenge of getting all the headers.
When I was creating a specific type of TOC in jekyll, I found [this piece of code](https://github.com/allejo/jekyll-toc/blob/master/_includes/toc.html) very helpfull. You can use elements from there.

A basic version of what you want would be the following. You'll have to tweak this  based on your set-up, but it should do what you want. You could put this in a seperate html doc in `_includes` or place it directly in your navbar.

```
{% for page in site.pages %}

<ul>
    {% assign headers = page.content | split: '<h' %}
        {% for header in headers %}
            {% assign _string = header | split: '</h' %}
            {% capture _hAttrToStrip %}{{ _string[0] | split: '>' | first }}>{% endcapture %}
            {% assign title = _string[0] | replace: _hAttrToStrip, '' %}

            {% assign _idstring = header | split: 'id="' %}
            {% assign _idstring = _idstring[1] | split: '"' %}
            {% assign html_id = _idstring[0] %}

            <li>
                <a href={{page.url}}#{{html_id}}>{{title}}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If your files are at root directory then they are not `posts`, but `pages`.

You can traverse such namespace like: `{% for page in site.pages %}`